# Cycling through fragments- states are null

Tags: android

I'm using a viewpager which has X fragments in it containing a question. Each fragment extends from the same fragment class so that I can call a method on each fragment in a loop. Here is what I mean:

```
     private int correctAnswers(){
        int NumberCorrect = 0;
        var activity = Activity as QuizActivity;
        var adapter = activity.getViewPagerAdapter ();
        List<questionFrag> fragList = new List<questionFrag> ();

        for (int i = 0; i < activity.getViewPagerAdapter ().Count - 1; i++) {
            var questionfrag = adapter.GetItem (i) as questionFrag;
            if (questionfrag.isCorrect()) {
                ++NumberCorrect;
            }
        }
        return NumberCorrect;
    }
```

The line "questionfrag.isCorrect()" allows me to cycle through the fragments and obtain whether a correct answer was obtained from each fragment. The correctAnswers function is called on the last fragment of the viewpager. However, when I call the method, all variables are null in the fragments. I thought the fragment states were saved inherently by setting "viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit" to include all fragments but they are not.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: How are you initializing those fragment variables?

Comment: @dhke Instantiated publicly at the start of the class, initialized in OnCreateView()

Comment: @shn-android-dev: Okay, then it's probably not the "usual" problem of Android using the default constructors of the fragment to (re-)create them after a configuration change that bites everybody relying on `newInstance()` and the like.

Comment: @dhke actually I do create each fragment with a newInstance() method, could this be the source of the problem? If so, how do I fix this? I read your initial question as the variables inside the fragment, not the fragment itself

Comment: I initialized my fragments' vars through set and get arguments. In newInstance () I create fragment and bundle with values to initialize and set to fragment with fragment.setArguments (). In onCreate () call getArguments () to receive all values and initialize. But in your case is initializing the problem? I think it's more about how are you receiving the answers and put them in your global variables.

Comment: @cgr I decided to just save my answers using SharedPreferences. If I have 100 fragments in a viewpager it would probably be best to not save all the fragment states anyways.

Comment: I was thinking that too. That's a good idea. You can tag orappend your preference keys with fragments position so you can track then easily. Also you can consider using statepageradapter and restrict your of screen page limit to 2 or 3 so only very few fragments will be kept in memory so there won't be any OOMs. This adapter saves the states and the same will be used when user visits back again.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the issue by saving my variables in SharedPrefereces. In the future I might save them using SQLite. Regardless, its probably not the best idea to allocate memory to save 100 fragment states.

Comment: That's fine. You can do so. To get what you're expecting you should use only FragmentPagerAdapter not the state pager adapter. And change your off screen page limit now.